# Why is this NSString null in a FireBase query block?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, objective-c-blocks, nsmutabledictionary

I can't figure out why this string is null inside the FQuery block. My app keeps crashing when I build the dailyLog MutableDictionary at the user key;

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, YYYY"];

NSString *userID = [[self.userProfile objectForKey:@"userID"] copy];
self.logFirebase = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:@"https://urlName.firebaseio.com/DailyLog"];
[[[self.logFirebase queryOrderedByPriority] queryEqualToValue:userID childKey:@"userID"] observeEventType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {

    if (![snapshot.value isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
        NSMutableArray *data = [CGCFirebaseDataExtractor extractKeysAndObjects:snapshot.value];

        self.dailyLog = [data filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Name CONTAINS[cd] %@",[df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]]].lastObject;
    }else{
        self.dailyLog = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"users Profile:%@",self.userProfile);
        NSLog(@"users ID :%@",[self.userProfile objectForKey:@"userID"]);

        [self.dailyLog setObject:[df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]] forKey:@"date"];
        [self.dailyLog setObject:[self.userProfile objectForKey:@"userID"] forKey:@"user"];
        [self.dailyLog setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:450] forKey:@"calories"];


        [[self.logFirebase childByAutoId] setValue:self.userProfile];

    }

}];
```

EDIT:
When I log self.userProfile, I get the proper info I want. But when I log the userID itself from within the FQuery block, it's null

Here is my updated crash data:

```
2015-05-08 13:21:22.709 <appname>[4160:1321097] users Profile:{
"-JoirTqCXFFDY1psLTNn" =     {
    dateRegistered = "1431010405.81792";
    userID = "304D92EF-CE77-4A10-A55F-9847153699F7";
    userName = "User's Name";
};
 }
 2015-05-08 13:21:22.709 <appname>[4160:1321097] users ID :(null)
 2015-05-08 13:21:22.714 <appname>[4160:1321097] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: user)'
  *** First throw call stack:
  (0x1852082d8 0x196a340e4 0x1850f1428 0x10007de00 0x1001454d0 0x100390fd4 0x100390f94 0x100395c28 0x1851bf7f8 0x1851bd8a0 0x1850e92d4 0x18e8ff6fc 0x189caefac 0x10007f14c 0x1970b2a08)
   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as your recent question that you deleted.

Comment: Your logging is bogus. The times and threads do not match up. Please rerun the app and paste the _actual results_ of one logging run.

Comment: the logging is still the same output

Comment: I understand, but it's important to see the real logging - thanks for pasting that in.

Comment: Okay, I finally figured it out! I am an idiot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I'm an idiot and didn't look closely at your log.

```
2015-05-08 13:21:22.709 <appname>[4160:1321097] users Profile:{
"-JoirTqCXFFDY1psLTNn" =     {
    dateRegistered = "1431010405.81792";
    userID = "304D92EF-CE77-4A10-A55F-9847153699F7";
    userName = "User's Name";
};
```

This object is evidently a dictionary in a dictionary. The first (outer) dictionary has key `"-JoirTqCXFFDY1psLTNn"` *and that is its only key*. That is why trying to get the key `userID` fails; that key is part of the second (inner) dictionary.

Comment: that is not causing the crash. I am trying to copy the data from userProfile into dailyLog. Whether the keys match in both dictionaries, or not, is irrelevant.

And I've used [self.userProfile objectForKey:@"userID"] also. It is still null

Comment: No, you are not trying to copy the data from userProfile. You are trying to use `userID` from the first line. But it is nil.

Comment: To rephrase, I've tried using [self.userProfile objectForKey:@"userID"]  and still get null

Comment: Silly me, I forgot to run that dictionary through my CGCFirebaseDataExtractor. It fixes that nested dictionary issue

Comment: I figured there was some way. I have no idea about firebase.

Comment: Thank god it's friday